# Reorganization and cleaning of a 'treeview' JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm

I want to create a JavaScript method that transforms a Json ‘treeView’ object. My starting object has a structure with duplicated branches:

**Example of basic data:**

```
- ROOT
    - 01
        - 011
            - 0111
    - 01
        - 011
            - 0112
    - 01
        - 011
            - 0113
    - 01
        - 012
            - 0121
    - 01
        - 012
            - 0122
    - 01
        - 012
            - 0123
    - 01
        - 013
            - 0131
    - 01
        - 013
            - 0132
    - 01
        - 013
            - 0133
```

I would like the method to group all the levels with an identical code.
And sort the items alphabetically.

**Example of what the method should return:**

```
- ROOT
    - 01
        - 011
            - 0111
            - 0112
            - 0113
        - 012
            - 0121
            - 0122
            - 0123
        - 013
            - 0131
            - 0132
            - 0133
```

**Example of basic data (Json):**

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "ROOT",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "01",
        "id": 3,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "013",
            "id": 2,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0131",
                "id": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "01",
        "id": 6,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "011",
            "id": 5,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0112",
                "id": 4
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "01",
        "id": 9,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "011",
            "id": 8,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0111",
                "id": 7
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "01",
        "id": 12,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "013",
            "id": 11,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0132",
                "id": 10
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "01",
        "id": 15,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "013",
            "id": 14,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0133",
                "id": 13
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "01",
        "id": 18,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "011",
            "id": 17,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0113",
                "id": 16
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "01",
        "id": 21,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "012",
            "id": 20,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0121",
                "id": 19,
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "01",
        "id": 24,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "012",
            "id": 23,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0122",
                "id": 22
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "01",
        "id": 27,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "012",
            "id": 26,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0123",
                "id": 25
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Example of what the method should return (json):**

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "ROOT",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "01",
        "id": 3,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "011",
            "id": 5,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0111",
                "id": 7
              },
              {
                "name": "0112",
                "id": 4
              },
              {
                "name": "0113",
                "id": 16
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "012",
            "id": 20,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0121",
                "id": 19,
              },
              {
                "name": "0122",
                "id": 22
              },
              {
                "name": "0123",
                "id": 25
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "013",
            "id": 2,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "0131",
                "id": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "0132",
                "id": 10
              },
              {
                "name": "0133",
                "id": 13
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

I think a recursive method would be the most appropriate, but I don't have too many ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for might be trie

But without much theory we can just write some code already

The idea is to consider your output as a tree.

Whenever you access a child of your data, you create a node corresponding to that child in the tree if it does not exists yet

Then your recurse, and in-fine you just have to get back your tree-like structure

```js
const data = [{"id":0,"name":"ROOT","children":[{"name":"01","id":3,"children":[{"name":"013","id":2,"children":[{"name":"0131","id":1}]}]},{"name":"01","id":6,"children":[{"name":"011","id":5,"children":[{"name":"0112","id":4}]}]},{"name":"01","id":9,"children":[{"name":"011","id":8,"children":[{"name":"0111","id":7}]}]},{"name":"01","id":12,"children":[{"name":"013","id":11,"children":[{"name":"0132","id":10}]}]},{"name":"01","id":15,"children":[{"name":"013","id":14,"children":[{"name":"0133","id":13}]}]},{"name":"01","id":18,"children":[{"name":"011","id":17,"children":[{"name":"0113","id":16}]}]},{"name":"01","id":21,"children":[{"name":"012","id":20,"children":[{"name":"0121","id":19}]}]},{"name":"01","id":24,"children":[{"name":"012","id":23,"children":[{"name":"0122","id":22}]}]},{"name":"01","id":27,"children":[{"name":"012","id":26,"children":[{"name":"0123","id":25}]}]}]}]

const makeTree = root => {
  const toTree = (trieNode, node) => {
    trieNode.children = trieNode.children || []
    let trieNodeChild = trieNode.children.find(child => child.name === node.name)
    if (!trieNodeChild) {
      trieNodeChild = { name: node.name, id: node.id }
      trieNode.children.push(trieNodeChild)
    }
    if (!node.children) return
    node.children.forEach(child => toTree(trieNodeChild, child))
    return trieNode
  }
  return toTree({}, root)
}
console.time('a')
console.log(JSON.stringify(makeTree(data[0]), null, 2))
console.timeEnd('a')
```

Note that it is not very efficient because searching in array is slow

A slightly improved version is to store the trieNodes in a map(name => trieNode)

```js
const makeTree2 = root => {
  const cache = new Map
  const toTree = (trieNode, node) => {
    trieNode.children = trieNode.children || []
    let trieNodeChild = cache.get(node.name)
    if (!trieNodeChild) {
      trieNodeChild = { name: node.name, id: node.id }
      trieNode.children.push(trieNodeChild)
      cache.set(node.name, trieNodeChild)
    }
    if (!node.children) return
    node.children.forEach(child => toTree(trieNodeChild, child))
    return trieNode
  }
  return toTree({}, root)
}
console.time('a2')
console.log(JSON.stringify(makeTree2(data[0]), null, 2))
console.timeEnd('a2')
```

On my potatoe, first code takes 5ms, second takes 0.3ms. Does not matter much for this data, but order of complexity is apparent.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot ! I really like the second solution. Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

We traverse the tree and remember the nodes that we have seen. If we encounter a node we have seen previously, we merge its children into the previously seen node and delete the node itself.

Note that different ids are picked, since we have to traverse the tree in "delete-safe" order.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myTree = [{ id: 0, name: 'ROOT', children: [{ name: '01', id: 3, children: [{ name: '013', id: 2, children: [{ name: '0131', id: 1 }] }] }, { name: '01', id: 6, children: [{ name: '011', id: 5, children: [{ name: '0112', id: 4 }] }] }, { name: '01', id: 9, children: [{ name: '011', id: 8, children: [{ name: '0111', id: 7 }] }] }, { name: '01', id: 12, children: [{ name: '013', id: 11, children: [{ name: '0132', id: 10 }] }] }, { name: '01', id: 15, children: [{ name: '013', id: 14, children: [{ name: '0133', id: 13 }] }] }, { name: '01', id: 18, children: [{ name: '011', id: 17, children: [{ name: '0113', id: 16 }] }] }, { name: '01', id: 21, children: [{ name: '012', id: 20, children: [{ name: '0121', id: 19 }] }] }, { name: '01', id: 24, children: [{ name: '012', id: 23, children: [{ name: '0122', id: 22 }] }] }, { name: '01', id: 27, children: [{ name: '012', id: 26, children: [{ name: '0123', id: 25 }] }] }] }];

const rewrite = (tree) => {
  const lookup = objectScan(['**(^children$)'], {
    useArraySelector: false,
    filterFn: ({ parent, property, value, context }) => {
      if (value.name in context) {
        if (Array.isArray(value.children)) {
          if (!Array.isArray(context[value.name].children)) {
            context[value.name].children = [];
          }
          context[value.name].children.push(...value.children);
        }
        parent.splice(property, 1);
      } else {
        context[value.name] = value;
      }
    }
  })(tree, {});
  const cmpFn = (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  Object.values(lookup)
    .filter((v) => Array.isArray(v.children))
    .forEach((v) => v.children.sort());
  tree.sort(cmpFn);
};

console.log(rewrite(myTree));
// => undefined

console.log(myTree);
// => [ { id: 0, name: 'ROOT', children: [ { name: '01', id: 27, children: [ { name: '012', id: 26, children: [ { name: '0123', id: 25 }, { name: '0122', id: 22 }, { name: '0121', id: 19 } ] }, { name: '011', id: 17, children: [ { name: '0113', id: 16 }, { name: '0111', id: 7 }, { name: '0112', id: 4 } ] }, { name: '013', id: 14, children: [ { name: '0133', id: 13 }, { name: '0132', id: 10 }, { name: '0131', id: 1 } ] } ] } ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@16.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)